# ng-template's let-item="item" throwing an error in Angular 8

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular8, ng-template

I have used ng-select for my requirement of searchable dropdown.
The dropdown is working perfectly fine. However there are html errors being thrown on ng-template.

i.e. `let-item="item"`
and if i make any change to the above line, the dropdown doesn't load.

this is the error thrown

`The template context of 'ɵf' does not define a member called 'item'ng(0)`

Though i am not facing any issue with the working of the dropdown, these errors are stopping me during CI/CD process. i.e. when i use `npm run-script build` these errors are displayed. Which will be effecting my prod release.

```
<ng-select required [items]="requestTypes" id="RequestTypeId" formControlName="RequestType" bindLabel="requestTypeName" appendTo="body" [(ngModel)]="accountFilters.requestTypeObject" placeholder="Select Client" class="font" [ngClass]="{ 'esubmit': submitted &amp;&amp; accountConfigForm.controls.RequestType.errors }">
  <ng-template ng-option-tmp let-item="item">
    <div title="{{item.requestTypeName}}">{{item.requestTypeName}}</div>
  </ng-template>
</ng-select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think  can be used only for else part of an  statement

eg:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="a=='value';else dosmthing"> 
  // if part 
</ng-container>
<ng-template #dosmthing>
// else part
</ng-template>
```

Try using this in your code is if you don't have else

```
<ng-select required [items]="requestTypes" id="RequestTypeId" formControlName="RequestType" bindLabel="requestTypeName" appendTo="body" [(ngModel)]="accountFilters.requestTypeObject" placeholder="Select Client" class="font" [ngClass]="{ 'esubmit': submitted &amp;&amp; accountConfigForm.controls.RequestType.errors }">
  <ng-container ng-option-tmp let-item="item">
    <div title="{{item.requestTypeName}}">{{item.requestTypeName}}</div>
  </ng-container >
</ng-select>
```